# Autosizing not working with page number special character

Tags: adobe-indesign

I created a master page with numbering in the corner like so:

[image]

It's width was set to auto size so that larger page numbers (say 233), would still format correctly. And it worked when I typed large numbers in by hand:

[image]

However, when I replaced it with the `Type > Insert Special Characters > Marker > Current Page`, this happened:

Master page:

[image]

Pages with master page applied to them:

[image]

These are the settings that show up when I hit cmd-B:
[image][image]

Any help would really be appreciated. I'm in a bind.

Answer (score 2):

Autosize bases the new size on the text in the frame. But the placeholder character for a page number doesn't have a definitive size - it can be smaller or (much) wider on every single page. It's either intentionally made so (for reasons of software design), or a straight out bug (and I suspect the latter, because text variables suffer from similar problems). So don't attempt to use Autosize for this.

The easiest alternative way is to add a very thick Paragraph Rule below, with its width set to Text Width and a small negative offset to its left and right. Make sure the entire text frame is wide enough for the widest possible number.